# parse text from xml

Tags: java, xml

I have following link

```
https://hero.epa.gov/hero/ws/swift.cfc?method=getProjectRIS&project_id=993&getallabstracts=true
```

I want to parse this xml to get only text, like

```
Provider: HERO - 2.xx
DBvendor=EPA
Text-encoding=UTF-8
```

How can I parse it ?

Comment: If you view the source code of that page, you'll see the [wddxPacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDDX) you mentioned. You *might* be able to [parse it as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962866/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-extract-plain-text-from-an-xml-document)... though I haven't tried.

Comment: you can install ARC ([Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)) from the chrome webstore to get more influence into the headers sent and see the request and response headers and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a text file, it's an HTML file. If you open a file in browser and select `view source` you will be able to see text enclosed in `<char>` tags.

When it's opened in browser, these tags and other `HTML` content is interpreted and output is rendered on the page (that's why it looks like a text). If you want to implement similar behavior in Java then you should look into [PhantomJS](https://github.com/detro/phantomjsdriver-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/tests/BaseTest.java) and/or [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) examples.

Comment: I need to parse this file. It there any easy way to do it? Like converting the file into xml/json, etc.?

Comment: I guess JSoup will be your best friend in this case

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a text file but it is an XML file and the browser just displays its text content.
To verify right click and look at the page source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like Jsoup for parsing the file and getting the contents.

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document